# Python OpenCV cv2.VideoWriter Error

Tags: python, opencv, camera, thermal-printer

I'm trying to export the data coming from a thermal camera but I get an error message that says

```
error: /build/opencv-ISmtkH/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:238: error: (-215) image->depth == 8 in function writeFrame
```

Can someone look at what I'm doing and tell me what I'm doing wrong? I followed and example pretty closely so I don't understand what this error means or why it's happening.

```
o = camera.add_overlay(np.getbuffer(a), size=(320,240), layer=3, alpha=int(alpha), crop=(0,0,80,60), vflip=flip_v)

filename = time.strftime("%Y.%m.%d  %H.%M.%S", time.localtime()) + ".avi"
fourcc =  cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('I','4','2','0')
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, fps, (width, height))

try:
  time.sleep(0.2) # give the overlay buffers a chance to initialize
  with Lepton(device) as l:
    last_nr = 0
    while True:
      _,nr = l.capture(lepton_buf)

      out.write(lepton_buf)

      if nr == last_nr:
        # no need to redo this frame
        continue
      last_nr = nr
      cv2.normalize(lepton_buf, lepton_buf, 0, 65535, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
      np.right_shift(lepton_buf, 8, lepton_buf)
      a[:lepton_buf.shape[0], :lepton_buf.shape[1], :] = lepton_buf
      o.update(np.getbuffer(a))
except Exception:
  traceback.print_exc()
finally:
  camera.remove_overlay(o)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change `out.write(lepton_buf)` to `out.write(np.uint8(lepton_buf))`

What you're trying to write isn't a number and that's what's confusing it.

Comment: That got rid of the error but the file that is outputted is always corrupt. Any idea why?

Comment: what do you mean by corrupt?

Comment: You're also missing a `out.release()` statement so the buffer isn't ever being emptied.

Comment: Did that too, yet the program continues to spit out an 8K file with nothing in it.

Comment: Try moving it to after the `a[:lepton_buf.shape[0], :lepton_buf.shape[1], :] = lepton_buf` line and resize.

Answer (score 1):

Several suggestions to try

Try a more common codec:

```
fourcc=cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X', 'V', 'I', 'D')
```

make sure your video dimensions fit the image dimensions. Try
swapping width and height, the order of these can be confusing.

```
height,width,channels=lepton_buf.shape
```

or specify directly width and height for your video:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, 8.0, (60, 80))
```

as stated before by @Crystal, make sure you convert your image data to data type 'uint8'

Try saving to a 'fresh' file name. Sometimes opencv videowriter silently fails saving to a file that hasn't been properly released from a previous access.

finally, release your file when done writing frames!

```
out.release()
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried the first suggest and it gave me a module error so I think I'm going to stick with the codec I have now. Also do you know if there is a way to confirm what the height and width of the video is? The datahsheet tells me the resolution is 80x60 but since I'm using someone else code to run the camera I wanted to make sure that my numbers were correct.

Comment: What system are you using? I am surprised xvid would not be available in your opencv/ffmpeg. Have you ever successfully saved any video via opencv on your computer?

Comment: your code specifies `out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, fps, (width, height))` . Where do you specify width and height?

Comment: check the format of your video data using `print lepton_buf.shape()` before your statement `out.write(lepton_buf)` . This will print for each frame and will also be a sanity check that frames are coming from your camera at all.

Comment: try `out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, 8.0, (60, 80))` instead

Comment: I ran into a similar issue and @AngelLockhart's suggestion to swap the width and height worked for me.